# Selectpicker validator forcing user to select a value

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc, multi-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am currently developing a web application using ASP.NET Core v2.2.

I'm having troubles in one of my forms where I have several "multiselect" (using bootstrap-select selectpicker). The problem is that the form doesn't allow users to not select any options in a multiselect before being submitted.

Here's an example of one of my multiselects that I'd like to be "optional" :

```
 <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post" role="form" id="bsForm">
       <div class="row row-mb-2">
          <div class="col col-sm-4">
              <label class="col-form-label" style="float:left">Product :</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
              <select asp-for="product.ProductId"
                      class="form-control selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true"
                      style="display: initial !important"
                      asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.ListOfProducts,"ProductId","ProductName"))">
                      <option data-hidden="true"></option>
              </select>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:25%" />
      </div>    
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });
</script>
```

When I'm looking into it (by inspecting the element), it looks like there is some kind of validator running and forbidding users to let these selectpickers not selected.

[image]

If you have any idea of how to disable this validator (or just the fact of forcing users to select a value), I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance !

**Edit :**

So I've found something that does the trick. I think that by doing so I removed every existing validations conditions. Here's what I did :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#bsForm').validate({
            rules: {
            }
      });
   });
</script>
```

Since this is kind of a butchering solution, I'm still looking for a better solution.

Comment: `asp-for` will generate validation span and data-required attribute if the ProductId property is marked with the [Required] attribute.  You can either delete the required attribute on model  or create new view model and not add the attribute . Or you can use jquery to remove rules like your codes .